Why is the spectrum of the Laplacian on the torus discrete?
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a finite open box of size $L$ with periodic boundary conditions and consider the Laplace operator $-\Delta$ on $L^{2}(\Omega)$ (actually, it acts on the Sobolev space $H^{2}(\Omega)$). It is easy to see that wave functions $e^{i\langle p,x\rangle}$, $p \in \frac{2\pi}{L} \mathbb{Z}^{d}$, are eigenfunctions of this Laplacian. However, all the books and references I know take this as sufficient proof that the spectrum of $-\Delta$ is discrete, that is, its essential spectrum is empty. This means that $-\Delta$ has only eigenvalues in the spectrum, and these have finite multiplicity. My question is: why is it the case? Any proof for the proof?

Can you give at least one such reference (and perhaps a mathematical one, because physicists are not very careful with the spectrum).

@TobiasFünke reference for the definition of the discrete/essential spectrum?

No, the claim itself. But yes, you could also include some proper definition of "discrete spectrum". (e.g. you miss the isolatedness, no?)

The normalized eigenfunctions of the self-adjoint operator under consideration form an orthonormal basis for the underlying Hilbert space. This means it has a pure point spectrum, and the only points in the spectrum which could be in the continuous spectrum are accumulation points of the eigenvalues, as discussed e.g. here.
These eigenvalues are, up to a multiplicative non-zero real pre-factor, $p^2= \sum_{i=1}^d n_i^2$ for some $n_i\in \mathbb Z$. So every eigenvalue in the spectrum of the Laplacian can be written as a sum over squares of integers, and there are only a finite number of such combinations, which means that the multiplicity of each eigenvalue is finite.
The eigenvalues are separated: Intuitively, going from one to another means to change at least one $n_i$, which is a finite step. That means that there is no accumulation point, because for every point on the real line which is not an eigenvalue you can choose an open neighborhood such that it contains no eigenvalue. We can therefore conclude that the spectrum consists precisely of the eigenvalues (there is no continuous part). In particular, this also shows that each eigenvalue is isolated.
We've thus shown that the spectrum consists precisely of the eigenvalues as introduced above, where each has a finite multiplicity and is isolated, or, equivalently: we've shown that the spectrum is discrete.

The direct reason for the fact that the spectrum is discrete is easy. The one parameter semi-group generated by the Laplacian $$e^{t\Delta},\quad t\geq 0$$
is a selfadjoint compact operator as it happens on every compact Riemannian manifold for the Laplacian ooerator with standard boundary conditions (Dirichlet, Neumann, periodic). This implies that its spectrum is discrete (up to the zero value possibly): i.e a point spectrum made of separated points with finite dimensional eigenspaces. In turn, from spectral calculus,  the spectrum of it is made of the elements $e^{-t\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $\Delta$. Hence the latter has discrete spectrum.
You can find the proof in every textbook on heat kernels on manifolds.
In the considered case, you can also prove it by direct inspection by computing the eigenvectors of the Laplacian with periodic conditions initially defined on the dense space of smooth periodic functions, where it defines a symmetric operator. It is important to note for later convenience that the found eigenvectors span finite dimensional eigenspaces.
From Nelson’s theorem,  the fact that this set of vectors is a Hilbert basis implies that the Laplacian is essentially selfadjoint on the span of these vectors, and also on the set of smooth periodic functions.
The unique selfadjoint extension has therefore the (closure) of the found set of eigenvalues as spectrum.
Since this set is made of separated points, the spectrum is a point spectrum. Since the eigenspaces have finite dimension, the spectrum is discrete in proper sense.

Thanks! Alternatively, can one prove the essential spectrum is empty by showing that its min-max values diverge? This was the strategy I was trying at first.

I do not know. I do not understand well your strategy….
